# Dictionary of sorted values gets unsorted when transformed into pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas

I am reading a csv file with the GDP for the 32 states in Mexico from 1940 to 2004. The columns are state names, and GDP values for each year.

Unfortunately, I can't add images just now... but, basically, the dataframe has as columns the following: state_name, 1940, 1950, etc... the values for state_name are the names of each state (as strings), and the values for the rest of the columns are the GDPs per state per year.

So, I am trying to produce a new dataframe in which there is no longer a state_names column, but only columns 1940, 1950, etc... where values are no longer the corresponding GDPs, but the names of the states according to the GDP in a given year. So, the column 1940 in the new dataframe would list the states not in alphabetical order, as I the current output does, but by the sorting of GDPs (as the one I have produced in my loop to create a dictionary below).

I am using the following loop to (in states) sort the entire data frame by each year (1940 to 2004), and then slice the names of this sorted data frame (in names).

```
ranks = {} 
for year in pibe.columns.values[1:]:
    states = pibe.sort(columns=year, ascending=False)
    names = states["entidad"]
    ranks[year] = names
```

The output of this dictionary looks like below:

```
{'1940': 1         Baja California
22           Quintana Roo
8        Distrito Federal
9                 Durango
21              Queretaro
0          Aguascalientes
2     Baja California Sur
...
Name: entidad, dtype: object, 
'1950': 22           Quintana Roo
1         Baja California
8        Distrito Federal
2     Baja California Sur
5     Chihuahua...}
```

So long so good. But, when I try to transform the dictionary into a data frame it somehow overrides my previous sorting and retrieves an alphabetically ordered list of state names. So, the new data frame has as columns each year populated by the same list of names.

To transform the dictionary into a data frame I am using:

```
pd.DataFrame(ranks)
```

Comment: Do you have some example input/output? As it looks like you could just not worry about the sorting to begin with, then just sort your DataFrame accordingly after...?

Comment: I added some sample output of the dictionary I have created, but I can't add images of the output data frame. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Another approach: don't worry about the dataframe storing the data sorted; don't analyze the data by iterating over the dataframe; when you use pandas' organizing functions, e.g. `groupby`, sort the results. tl;dr - let pandas do the work, it's smarter than a csv. Also, do you know about MultiIndex on dataframes? you're starting with that kind of data.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new dataframe based on the ordering that you need:

```
In [6]: ordered_df = original_df.sort(['Year','GDP'],axis=0,ascending=False)
```

Create a new dictionary to pass into the final dataframe (this can be done more efficiently):

```
In [7]: unique_years = {item[1]['Year']:[] for item in ordered_df.iterrows()}
```

Loop through new dataframe populating the dictionary:

```
In [8]: for row in ordered_df.iterrows():
            unique_years[row[1]['Year']].append(row[1]['State'])
```

Create final dataframe:

```
In [9]: final_df = pd.DataFrame(unique_years)
```

Input:

```
In [11]: original_df
Out[11]: 
    Year       State  GDP
0   1945    New York   84
1   1945       Texas   38
2   1945  California   84
3   1946    New York   56
4   1946       Texas    6
5   1946  California   84
6   1947    New York   75
7   1947       Texas   95
8   1947  California   92
9   1948    New York   50
10  1948       Texas   25
11  1948  California   30
12  1949    New York   16
13  1949       Texas   33
14  1949  California   31
15  1950    New York   37
16  1950       Texas   75
17  1950  California   49
18  1951    New York   28
19  1951       Texas   74
20  1951  California   78
21  1952    New York   57
22  1952       Texas    5
23  1952  California   28
```

Output:

```
In [12]: final_df
Out[12]: 
         1945        1946        1947        1948        1949        1950  \
0    New York  California       Texas    New York       Texas       Texas   
1  California    New York  California  California  California  California   
2       Texas       Texas    New York       Texas    New York    New York   

         1951        1952  
0  California    New York  
1       Texas  California  
2    New York       Texas
```

Check final dataframe against the ordered dataframe to ensure proper GDP ordering:

```
In [13]: ordered_df
Out[13]: 
    Year       State  GDP
21  1952    New York   57
23  1952  California   28
22  1952       Texas    5
20  1951  California   78
19  1951       Texas   74
18  1951    New York   28
16  1950       Texas   75
17  1950  California   49
15  1950    New York   37
13  1949       Texas   33
14  1949  California   31
12  1949    New York   16
9   1948    New York   50
11  1948  California   30
10  1948       Texas   25
7   1947       Texas   95
8   1947  California   92
6   1947    New York   75
5   1946  California   84
3   1946    New York   56
4   1946       Texas    6
0   1945    New York   84
2   1945  California   84
1   1945       Texas   38
```

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to sort for each year and then create a new data frame with only the state names by year sorted by the GDP in that year. (Something like the second solution you propose, but "gluing" the results for each year in a single data frame). The new data frame would not have an independent state_names column, but instead only columns ranging from 1940-2004 where the values are the state names sorted by that year's GDP.

Comment: I see now. I will need to revise my answer.

Comment: I built a small test case. Let's assume the GDP numbers are much bigger than the test case numbers :).